# Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on array

Tags: laravel

I have a `multiple` image. When I upload multiple image. I get this error.

> Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on array

my blade

```
<form action="{{ route('design-studios.store') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" value="{{ old('title') }}">
    </div>
   //......
    <div class="form-group">
        <fieldset class="border p-3">
            <legend>Slideshow</legend>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="sliders">Image</label>
                <input id="sliders" name="sliders[]" type="file" multiple class="form-control">
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</form>
```

My Controller.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $design_studio = new DesignStudio;
    $design_studio->user_id = 1;
    $design_studio->title = $request->title;
    $design_studio->lang = $request->lang;
    $design_studio->body = $request->body;
    if($request->has('image')) {
        $image = $request->file('image');
        $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();
        $image->move(public_path('images/design-studio'), $filename);
        $design_studio->image = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
    }
    if ($sliders = $request->file('sliders')) {
        foreach ($sliders as $slider) {
            $filename = $slider->getClientOriginalName();
            $slider->move(public_path('images/design-studio'), $filename);
            $design_studio->sliders = $request->file('sliders')->getClientOriginalName();
        }
    }
    $design_studio->save();
    $design_studio->categories()->attach($request->category);
    return redirect()->route('design-studios.index');
}
```

My Model

```
protected $casts = [
    'sliders' => array()
];
```

I get this error.

> Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on array

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to call that method on the file you are looping through instead of trying to call it on the array of files.

```
$design_studio->sliders = $slider->getClientOriginalName();
```

Comment: I see this error now: `strncmp() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`